# What is the easiest way to get the number of rows affected in an AFTER TRUNCATE trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, count

I'm trying to capture a count after TRUNCATE on a table, and am a bit stuck. Postgres 11.x on RDS. The context isn't complicated, a single-level, statement-level trigger (not a cascade.) All I need is the count of truncated records. For an UPDATE trigger, I can get the count of deleted rows off of a transition table, but TRUNCATE doesn't support transitions tables.

It seems like GET DIAGNOSTICS ROW_COUNT should do the trick. I get a new row in the deletion_log, but the deleted record count is 0. Here's my unsuccessful code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_truncate_statement_log_count() 
    RETURNS trigger
    AS $$
DECLARE
  deleted_count int := 0;
BEGIN

    GET DIAGNOSTICS deleted_count = ROW_COUNT;

   insert into deletion_log 
               (schema_name, table_name, deleted_count)

         select TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, deleted_count;

    return null;                   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Below is the code for the deletion_log table the trigger is meant to insert into:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deletion_log (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    deletion_dts timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    client_address inet DEFAULT inet_client_addr(),
    schema_name text DEFAULT get_current_user(),
    table_name text NOT NULL,
    deleted_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

COMMIT;
```

I've got the DELETE trigger firing correctly, but not the TRUNCATE. As an example, I'm testing it out on a scratch table named goals (from Postgres Weekly this morning):

```
CREATE TABLE goals (
  team TEXT, year INT, goals INT);

INSERT INTO goals VALUES
  ('USA', 2010, 5), ('USA', 2011, 3),
  ('USA', 2012, 12), ('ENG', 2010, 17),
  ('ENG', 2011, 9), ('ENG', 2012, 11);
```

Here's the trigger setup:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_delete_log_count_goals ON goals;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_log_count_goals AFTER DELETE ON goals
   REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS deleted_rows FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_delete_log_count();

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_truncate_log_count_goals ON goals;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_truncate_log_count_goals AFTER TRUNCATE ON goals
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_truncate_log_count();
```

I'm guessing that I've missed something basic. What is the easiest way to get the number of rows affected in an AFTER TRUNCATE trigger?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Truncate does not count rows, which is why it's usually faster than delete.  It just removes the file backing the table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I'm wondering, what _can_ you do in an AFTER TRUNCATE trigger? I've looked around for examples and haven't found much of anything. Maybe this is why?

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy's comment got me thinking, and I tried a count(*). This seems to work in a BEFORE TRUNCATE statement trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_truncate_log_count() 
    RETURNS trigger
    AS $$
DECLARE
  deleted_count int := 0;
BEGIN

   EXECUTE 'select count(1) from ' || TG_TABLE_NAME into deleted_count;

   insert into deletion_log  
              (operation_name, 
               schema_name,  
               table_name, 
               deleted_count)

        select TG_OP, 
               TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, 
               TG_TABLE_NAME, 
               deleted_count;

    return null;                   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I added TG_OP to my deletion_log table to see DELETE or TRUNCATE in the log.

Thanks for the help, and comments on gotchas or details I might not have thought of appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a decent approach if you don't mind the performance penalty.  Just be careful using TG_TABLE_NAME in your trigger.  It could count the wrong table if there are multiple tables with the same name.  It's probably better to use: `EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT count(1) FROM %s INTO deleted_count', TG_RELID::regclass);`

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks a lot! I'll go back and rework the code.

Comment: For the sake of anyone finding this thread later, here's how I reworked the code:

EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT count(*) FROM %s', TG_RELID::regclass)
   INTO deleted_count;

If you're reading this and don't know what regclass is, or why you would want it, check it out!

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html

Comment: For completeness, I tried GET DIAGNOSTICS ROW_COUNT in the BEFORE TRUNCATE trigger and it returns 0. Not sure how GET DIAGNOSTICS is meant to behave in a BEFORE.